# pytesseract not working

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> import pytesseract
>>> i=Image.open("C:\Users\dharaneeshvrd\Desktop\img.jpg
```

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

```
>>> i=Image.open("C:\Users\dharaneeshvrd\Desktop\img.jpg")
>>> print pytesseract.image_to_string(i)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       print pytesseract.image_to_string(i)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 161,
>   in image_to_string
>       config=config)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 94,
>   in run_tesseract
>       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo) WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>
> > > >

What i have done wrong here?
I have installed the pytesseract using pip as

```
pip install pytesseract
```

and pillow as

```
pip install pillow
```

Answer (score 2):

As specified in the error:

> The system cannot find the file specified

The filename - *C:\Users\dharaneeshvrd\Desktop\img.jpg* -  is in-correct (or doesn't exists).

Assuming that you are running on Ubuntu, the file name format should be different.

I'd suggest first, identifying the file in your drive and second, issue:

```
ls -lsa /full/path/name
```

to make sure that you wrote the path correctly, and afterwards use it in the python script